# unresolved overloaded function type [int] when implementing graph

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search

I try to implement graph bfs but get compiler error
error:

```
invalid types '<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]' for array subscript|
```

My questions:

1. Is my approach making array of vector of struct is right approach? And how can I solve the compiler error?
2. How to initialize array value to infinity?
3. When making undirected graph, should I push back 2 times?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#define INT_MAX 21422

using namespace std;

int distancee[10]={4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}; //want to intialize all to infinity
struct bfss{
    int firstt;
    int secondd;
};

vector<bfss>bfs[10];

void bfsfunc(int start){
    deque<int> q;
    q.push_back(start);
    distancee[start]=0;
    while(!q.empty()){
        int v=q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        for(int i=0;i<bfs[v].size();i++){

            if(distance[bfs[v][i].firstt]>(distance[v]+bfs[v][i].secondd)){ // got error in this line
                distance[bfs[v][i].firstt]=distance[v]+bfs[v][i].secondd;

                if(bfs[v][i].second==0)
                {
                    q.push_front(bfs[v][i].first);
                } else {
                    q.push_back(bfs[v][i].second);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int edges,nodes,x,y,z;
    cin>>edges>>nodes;
    for(int i=0;i<edges;i++){
        cin>>x>>y>>z; //x is array subscript , y is node(x-y is edge) , z is weight

        bfss newbfs;
        newbfs.firstt=y;
        newbfs.secondd=z;
        bfs[x].push_back(newbfs);

        bfss newbfs;
        newbfs.firstt=x;
        newbfs.secondd=z;
        bfs[y].push_back(newbfs);  // when making undirected graph, should i push back 2 times?
    }

    bfsfunc(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I indented my code why it not showing?

Comment: Apparently, code formatting is not recognized right after ordered list for some reason. I've no idea why tbh.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ok, thankyou so much for the edit! :D

Comment: `distance` must be `distancee` every where, and some `second` must be `secondd`

Comment: @Vixf you have `distance` instead of `distnacee`, and you'd easily catch this error (with better error message) if you didn't `use namespace std;` which is a bad practise (as demonstrated by your code, since it conflicted with `std::distance`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you had a few typos on distancee, firstt and secondd. Fix those and the errors goes away. For an `int` the closest you'll come to infinity is it's max value. With that and a few other minor changes (comments in the code), this is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

// removed using namespace std;

// max distance: not infinity, but hopefully large enough
constexpr int md = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

// replaced the C array with a standard C++ array
std::array<int, 10> distancee={md,md,md,md,md,md,md,md,md,md};

struct bfss {   // shouldn't these be unsigned?
    int firstt;
    int secondd;
};

std::vector<std::vector<bfss>> bfs(10); // replaced C array with a standard C++ vector

void bfsfunc(int start) {
    std::deque<int> q;
    q.push_back(start);
    distancee[start]=0;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        int v=q.front();
        q.pop_front();

        // using size_t intstead of int for array subscript
        for(size_t i=0;i<bfs[v].size();i++) {

            if(distancee[bfs[v][i].firstt]>(distancee[v]+bfs[v][i].secondd)) {
                distancee[bfs[v][i].firstt]=distancee[v]+bfs[v][i].secondd;

                if(bfs[v][i].secondd==0) {
                    q.push_front(bfs[v][i].firstt);
                } else {
                    q.push_back(bfs[v][i].secondd);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int edges,nodes,x,y,z;
    std::cin>>edges>>nodes;
    for(int i=0;i<edges;i++) {
        std::cin>>x>>y>>z; //x is array subscript , y is node(x-y is edge) , z is weight

        // using emplace_back to let the vector create the bfss in place
        bfs[x].emplace_back(bfss{y, z});
        bfs[y].emplace_back(bfss{x, z});
    }

    bfsfunc(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know the answer to the question about pushing twice since I don't know the algorithm.